# systemd start as unprivileged user in a group

Tags: systemd

I'd like users in group `foogroup` to be able to:

- `systemctl start foo.service`,
- `systemctl stop foo.service`,
- `systemctl status foo.service`, and
- `journalctl -u foo.service`

without using elevated privileges.  Is that possible?

---

I have a systemd service which looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=foo service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sleep infinity
User=foobot
Group=foogroup
```

Where `foobot` is a system user.

I know we can install the unit file to `~/.config/systemd/user/` to allow an unprivileged user to use systemd, but this doesn't really help a group.

Note: I plan on using [cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/) so adding `systemctl` to `/etc/sudoers` isn't going to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have accepted Tollef Fog Heen's answer if I wasn't on a Debian distribution, however because debian uses polkit (<0.106), *.rules are not available.  The equivalent file in Debian is:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/manage-units.pkla
----
[Allow users to manage services]
Identity=unix-group:somegroup
Action=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
ResultActive=yes
```

However, be warned that this is not exactly equivalent.  It allows a group to manage services, but doesn't specify which services the group is allowed to manage.   Also, it doesn't limit which 'verb' is permitted.  However I have noticed that while `systemd start` is permitted, things like `systemd enable` are still unavailable which is protected by file permissions.

I have another open question on SO regarding the differences between the capabilities of the `*.rules` and the `*.pkla` files of this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507975/systemd-service-management-using-pkla-equivalents-to-polkits-rules-on-debian).

Comment: Please remember to mention your Linux distribution. Debian is a very strange beast (in this case they have held back polkit since 2012 for no apparent reason!) and people need to be warned if you're using it or one of its derivatives, otherwise they might not be able to give you answers that are useful to you.

Comment: I had to add `ResultAny=yes`and `ReslutInactive=yes` to get it working.

Answer (score 3):

In /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-myservice.rules

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" && subject.isInGroup("somegroup")) {
        if (action.lookup("unit") == "foo.service") {
            var verb = action.lookup("verb");
            if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart") {
                return polkit.Result.YES;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Warning: this does not work on Debian or Ubuntu based systems, because Debian has chosen to hold back polkit to an ancient version from 2012. I have no idea why.

Comment: Your right, `wheezy`, `jessie`, `stretch` and `buster` are all on version 0.105 from 2012.  The `experimental` repository currently has version 0.115 from July 2018.

Comment: I'm seeing some Debian-deployed rules in `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/` which use the same features as described in this example, using `polkit.addrule()`, `action.id`, `subject.isInGroup()`, `polkit.Result.YES`.The only things missing from any of my examples is `action.lookup()`.    I'll give this a try and report back.